# Textfield inside Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this

```
<div id="mainDiv">
    <input type="text" value="Here is the text" />
</div>
<input type="button" value="Push" onclick="changeText()">
```

When I push the button I want to change the value from textfield.

Only this value I want to be changed because in my page there are a lot of textfields but those values must remain unchanged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
<div id="mainDiv"> 
<input type="text" value="Here is the text" /> 
</div> 
<input type="button" value="Push" onclick="document.getElementById('mainDiv').children[0].value='asd'">
```

Answer (score 1):

Well then, maybe this will help:

```
<script>
    function changeText() {
        var tf = document.getElementById('mainDiv').childNodes[0];
        tf.value = 'some text';
    }
</script>


<div id="mainDiv"><input type="text" value="Here is the text" /></div>
<input type="button" value="Push" onclick="changeText();">
```

Comment: Sorry, i forget to add this remark The structure of the div i cannot change. It's generated from DataTables Jquery. Adding a id it's very easy, but unfortunately i cannot do that

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this? Basically toggles the input to static text?

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LfLXJ/1/)**

```
function changeText(){
    var mainDiv = $("#mainDiv");
    mainDiv.text(mainDiv.children('input').val()); 
}
```

If you have multiple input fields per div this solution will work,

**[Live Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/LfLXJ/6/)**

```
function changeText(){
    var mainDiv = $("#mainDiv"),
        inputText = "";

    if(mainDiv.children('input').length > 0){
        mainDiv.children('input').each(function(){
          inputText += $(this).val();  
        });
        mainDiv.text(inputText); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind the id of the textbox with the id of the substring with a code
like this:

```
<div id="mainDiv"> <input type="text" value="Here is the text" id="input-324" /> </div> <input type="button" value="Push" onclick="changeText(this.id.replace("button-", ""))" id="button-324" >

<script>
    function changeText(id) {
        document.getElementById(id).value='myvalue';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, i forget to add this remark The structure of the div i cannot change. It's generated from DataTables Jquery.

Comment: I havent change the structure, ive only changed the parameter passed from changeText() to changeText(this)

Comment: Like i told you, on my page there are a lot of textfields. Try to add two more and see if it's ok.